# Google sheets jump to cell

Tags: google-sheets

I only complete entries in e.g. columns A to R, I would then like to automatically jump back to the next free cell in column A. This is in a shared sheet. Can anyone tell me how to do this as a complete novice?

Also when I first open the sheet I would also like it to go to the first free cell in column A.

I have tried looking through many answers and can see several questions asking the same but can't seem to get anything that actually does what I want.

I would need detailed instructions.

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: If one of the posters answered your question, please select it as The Answer, @J-A.

Answer (score 7):

You should write custom js code in script editor.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Go To End', functionName: 'goToEnd'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('My Menu', menuItems);
}
function goToEnd() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  //Browser.msgBox('values: ' + lastRow + '-' + lastColumn);
  sheet.setCurrentCell(lastCell);
}
```

For more [Google App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Answer (score 4):

There's a great video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqmCoCmxhZc) that shows how you can do this.

If you're not into watching the video:

- Open this Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/tamirko/da69818c4ced9b71cff4ce236b9dd4bd).
- Open Google Sheets.
- Go to Tools -> Script Editor.
- Enter the script (replace the text that appears there), and
  save it as something like goToCell.
- Refresh Google Sheets. A menu appears, goToCell.
- Open it, and follow prompts to authorise it.

Now you have a goToCell menu option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using shortcut keys, specifically Ctrl + Left ?
Ctrl + Left selects the next empty cell to the left or the final cell in the row.

1. Once the user has filled in columns A - R, pressing Ctrl + Left will take them to column A.
2. Then pressing Ctrl + Down will take them to the first row with an empty A cell.

Sometimes a simpler solution is best. This answer is ported from [Doc Editor Help](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0v-e0fVMPvvM/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/docs/v-e0fVMPvvM).